# Sharepoint 2010 new, display and edit form attachment menu

Tags: sharepoint-designer, attachments

I have an issue to propose.

I have a newform.aspx.  when one of my clients fill in the form and click in the "Attach File" button in the ribbon, the attach file window appears, that prompts you to upload a document from the local disk.  However, when he clicks on the "OK" button after uploading the document, the file is uploaded but the window does not close. I then have to click on "cancel" to go back to my form to find the attachment below the form.

According to you, is this an issue with the html code in the "OK" button?
If so, I looked for the attachment page but could not find it, so there is no possible way i can edit the html of the attachment page?

Regards,
Vish

Comment: I need some urgent help on this please.

Comment: 2 years ago. Did you solve it? If yes, can you post your solution?